# Is the function surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

Is the function $f:\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$; $f(m,n)=m^2-2n^2$ surjective?

Failed showing that $m^2=5+2n^2 \implies m$ is not an integer with induction...

Comment: what are the possible values of $f \pmod 8 \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: Please note the changes made via MathJax to your post. You can use MathJax to improve the mathematics presentation in your posts and a very nice tutorial for MathJax can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$m^2=5+2n^2$$
$$\implies (\exists k\in \Bbb Z) \;:\; m=2k+1$$

$$\implies 4k^2+4k+1=5+2n^2$$
$$\implies 2k^2+2k=2+n^2$$
$$\implies (\exists p\in \Bbb Z) \;:\; n=2p$$
$$\implies k(k+1)=1+2p^2$$

which is impossible since $( k(k+1)-2p^2 )$

is always even.

So $ f $ is not surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much!